# Range query includes the date given or exclude it?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I am working with range query in ELK stack. Suppose I am retrieving records with GTE only, so will the resultant records time will be = the GTE date provided or >= the GTE date provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTE = "Greater or Equal"

So the resulting records will be >= the provided date.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. :)

Comment: Val, is there a way to get only greater than and not GTE?

Comment: Yes, use `gt` instead of `gte` :-)